# How to debug a library from an application in Angular v10 with VS Code

Tags: angular, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code, angular-library

I have created, built and npm published a library called @abc/library.

In my application I declared it in package.json and installed with npm install (I have it now in application node-modules/@abc/library folder).

Everything works fine but now I am looking for a way to debug the library from my application, allowing me to directly access its source code and place breakpoints (in node-module I can access only declarations, located in d.ts files).

Following advices from other threads I tried:

- Setting npm link on library main folder (`npm link`) and in application main folder (`npm link "@abc/library"`)
- Setting sourceMap for scripts, style and vendor to true in application angular.json file:

```
"build": {
  "options": {
    "sourceMap": {
      "scripts": true,
      "styles": true,
      "vendor": true
     }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately nothing seems to work for me

**Update**

I found that after adding sourceMap options in application angular.json file, I'm able to debug the library in Chrome dev tools by following the path:

```
webpack://.node_modules/@abc/projects/library/src/lib
```

still though, I cannot debug it directly in Visual Studio Code

Comment: but only in the browser, not in VS Code, right?

Comment: Have you found a solution for the problem?